# Where are my favorite questions?

Tags: support, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)
>   [What can we do for new users who want to ask a question that's already been asked, but hasn't yet got an acceptable answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54329/what-can-we-do-for-new-users-who-want-to-ask-a-question-thats-already-been-aske)

Where are my favourite questions? What to do if I want to ask a question but it does already exist but has no answers?

Comment: Which of the _two_ questions are you actually asking here?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How do favorite questions work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/) and [What can we do for new users who want to ask a question that's already been asked, but hasn't yet got an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54329/). Related: What should you do when your question has already been asked, but... [badly?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138198/); [has no recent answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79823/); [the answers don't help you?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112980/)

Answer (score 4):

Your favorite questions are listed in your profile under the favorite tab.

And if you want to ask a question which already exists, you can [place a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) on the existing one for added attention, should you have enough rep to do so.

P.s. please limit yourself to a single question per question next time...

Comment: By the way, Congratulation for 10K. :)

Comment: @hims056 Haha, thanks. Meta 10k. The most meaningless 10k possible.